# spotify-web-api-node - WebapiError: Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

```
var SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');

var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId : 'xxx',
    clientSecret : 'xxx',
    redirectUri : 'https://example.com/callback'
});

spotifyApi.getTrack('2q8eudK0r9ImgCB1XhFfxG').then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

My code worked but for 1 month I have this error.

> (node:12824) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection (rejection id: 1): WebapiError: Unauthorized
>
> (node:12824)
> DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
> the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
> Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: take a look here https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node/issues/86

Comment: I have already regenerate the client ID, and secret ID...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node/issues/86) you need to set an access token.

```
spotifyApi.setAccessToken('myAccessToken');
```

Also, take a look here: https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node#setting-credentials

```
// Set necessary parts of the credentials on the constructor
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId : 'myClientId',
  clientSecret : 'myClientSecret'
});

// Get an access token and 'save' it using a setter
spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant()
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']);
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
  });

// Get tracks in a playlist
spotifyApi.getPlaylistTracks('thelinmichael', '3ktAYNcRHpazJ9qecm3ptn', { 'offset' : 1, 'limit' : 5, 'fields' : 'items' })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('The playlist contains these tracks', data.body);
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! I had found the solution in the meantime.